# UP Date: How remove sample from tf.data.dataset with missing or NaN values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

**Up Date**
I add this command to clear sample with missing values who lead my neural network to fail:

```
ds = ds.ignore_errors()
```

I use this function to remove all samples with NaN or missing values... but it don't work well

```
def filter_nan_sample(ds):
    # find NaN
    ynan = tf.math.is_nan(ds)
    y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(ynan, tf.float32))
    if y >0:
        return False
    return True

ds = ds.filter(filter_nan_sample)
# catch all sample with "defect" like missing values
ds = ds.ignore_errors()
```

I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Field 4 is required but missing in record! [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

field 4 match with a variable not always availlable in the record.
It is not inpossible in my case to deal this problem before turning data to dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how the "missing field" is related with the nan filters, but the nan filter itself can use some upgrade because using plain `if`s on a tensor can cause trouble sometimes.

```py
def filter_nan_sample(ds):
    # find NaN
    ynan = tf.math.is_nan(ds)
    return tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.reduce_any(ynan))  # True if no NaNs
```

Comment: excellent, Im happy to remove if of this code, thank for your help.... but as you said I dont find how catch if there is a missing value(s) so if you have any idea...

Comment: @JonathanRoy I would be curious to see some examples of the correct and failing data entries. What is in each record?

Comment: I found that using too big shuffle buffer the step earlie introduce NaN in the lasts samples, so I correct this by lower buffer. The .ignore_error is supose to catch all sample not compatible if I correctly understand and remove it

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to use `print(ds.as_numpy_iterator())` to see each of the items in the dataset, and identify which items might cause the problem? But I think it's generally easier if we can see the entire code for the dataset pipeline